# Mef, passing parameters to a module

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef

I'm studying MEF and I'm not able to resolve a problem.

I have a main application, called MainMEF, and a simple module, called SimpleModule. This one consists of a single UserControl which is loaded dynamically.

When MainMEF starts up, I would be able to pass to the module a reference to main application contained into MainMEF.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of questions regarding this already.
You could pass it after initialisation using a property:
[How do I populate a MEF plugin with data that is not hard coded into the assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939867/how-do-i-populate-a-mef-plugin-with-data-that-is-not-hard-coded-into-the-assembly)

Or use MEF constructor parameters:
[MEF Constructor Parameters with Multiple Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941158/mef-constructor-parameters-with-multiple-constructors)

The export looks something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(ITest))]
class Test : ITest 
{
    void Test() 
    {  }

    [ImportingConstructor] //<- This is the key bit here
    void Test(object parameter) 
    {  }
}
```

Then when composing your catalog do this:

```
catalog.ComposeExportedValue( /* parameter here */);
catalog.ComposeParts(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Very helpful. Could you explain me these lines with more code? Take into account catalog.
###
catalog.ComposeExportedValue( /* parameter here */);
catalog.ComposeParts(this);
###

What kind of type does it belong to?